# State not updating inside stack.Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

State is not being updated when the screen is placed inside `<Stack.Navigator>`

```
export default function App() {
    const Stack=createNativeStackNavigator()
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name='TestScreen' children={TestScreen}/>
            </Stack.Navigator> 
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Test screen is as:

```
const TestScreen = () => {
    const [currentCell, setCurrentCell] = useState(1)
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>{currentCell}</Text>
            <Button
                title='change'
                onPress={()=>setCurrentCell(currentCell==1?2:1)}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

If App is replaced with following code it works

```
export default function App() {
    const Stack=createNativeStackNavigator()
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <TestScreen/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

How can I solve the problem?
https://snack.expo.dev/@rujengelal/ashamed-edamame

Comment: It should `component` not `children`. It should be `<Stack.Screen name='TestScreen' component={TestScreen}/>`

Answer (score 1):

As @YoussoufOumar mentioned in the comments, `Stack.Screen` takes a `component`, not `children`.
So you're code should look like this

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="TestScreen" component={TestScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
const TestScreen = () => {
  const [currentCell, setCurrentCell] = useState(1);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>{currentCell}</Text>
      <Button
        title="change"
        onPress={() => setCurrentCell(currentCell == 1 ? 2 : 1)}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Here is a snack to test it https://snack.expo.dev/@mohammed-handa/state-not-updating-inside-stack-navigator